# The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not ref

Tags: c#, .net

I know this error is common but I couldn't find any SO question to solve my problem .

I have this piece of code :

```
    public static T _download_serialized_json_data<T>(string url) where T : new()
    {
            //This Line raise the error
            JsonConvert.ToObject(await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(url));
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            //This line raise a second error(same as the first one)
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(json_data) ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json_data) : new T();
     }
```

I'm getting an error regarding the first and last lines of my code

> Error   CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

As if JsonConvert doesn't contain a definition for ToObject and DeserializeObject . I don't understand which reference am I missing . The wierd thing is, if I add another class on a different page, and add this method there with the same `using` , no error appears .

My csproj :

```
  <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Ver sion="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: well... might change to `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`. I might be wrong - but there is netstandart 2.0 (https://github.com/dotnet/standard) for now.  Not 2.1.

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks but the error remains the same .

Answer (score 0):

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
```

No idea how that happened, but that needs to be

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: It just add more errors.. about incompatibility between versions

Comment: I don't know what messed up your project, but you might be better off recreating the project from scratch (and then copy all your code files over).

Comment: I already tried that, the problem is the a new project is being created with old versions in the nuget packages, which forces me to override it to a newer version, which brings the problem again haha .. How can I globaly update all the nuget packages versions?

Comment: You just open it in Visual Studio, click manage nuget packages and then go to update... this should not change your target framework.